# Print number of lines of an external file

Tags: external-files

I would like to print in a `.tex` file the number of lines of some other file (not the content, just how many lines).

For example in the following code I would like to have `3` print in the text

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
a
b
c
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Here should be the number of lines in test.txt

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prints 7 not 3 as the file has 7 lines due to comments, but:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
a
b
c
\end{filecontents}

\newread\zzz
\newcount\zzzlines
\begin{document}

Here should be the number of lines in test.txt

\zzzlines=-1
\openin\zzz=test.txt
\loop
\ifeof\zzz
\else
\read\zzz to \zzztmp
\advance\zzzlines 1
\repeat
\the\zzzlines

\end{document}
```

`test.txt` is

```
%% LaTeX2e file `test.txt'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `bb988' on 2019/07/09.
%%
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `knitr`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|test.txt| have \Sexpr{length(readLines("test.txt"))} lines
\end{document}
```

Will produce:

> `test.txt` have 3 lines